# How did this survive the snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Hulk used

> Tony’s Gauntlet to snap everyone back into existence.

A release of power of that magnitude

> nearly destroyed the original Infinity Gauntlet, and that was made of enchanted Uru, the same stuff Thor’s hammer and axe are made of.

So how did this item survive, if it was made of a lesser material?

Comment: define survive...

Comment: Also who said the Iron Man Gauntlet was "lesser"? Asgardian "enchanted" in the MCU just means "technology that looks like magic"

Comment: @NKCampbell if you look at it it seems to be in better shape than the original gauntlet was

Comment: Is Uru actually named in the MCU?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I thought it was but now you mention it I'm not sure.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it might be somewhere, there is a *lot* of MCU. But it certainly wasn’t treated as a plot point in any of the movies, including the one where Mjolnjr is destroyed, and I’m pretty sure *Infinity War* doesn’t state which metal is used on Nidavellir. (Also in 14 million possible futures, there’s only one where I spell both of those correctly from memory. I wonder if this was it.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I checked the _Thor_ and _Infinity War_ transcripts and neither mention Uru and they'd be the ones I'd imagine are most likely to mention it in the films.

Comment: Nanobots rearranged themselves after discarding damaged ones.

Comment: @Pauli_D - Nah, it's the other way around: technology is actually a kind of magic. That's why it is just as capable of kissing the laws of physics goodbye as anything that Doctor Strange can do, and can only be properly created by sorcerers like Shuri or Tony Stark: no magic superhero technology has been mass-produced for the public in the MCU, after all.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** I am currently in the process of trying to verify if the Stark Gauntlet was made out of Vibranium. So far the only theory I can think of for why it might be is that he could have re-purposed Vibranium from Ultron or someone could have taken some out of Wakanda in the time gap.

With that said I would take this answer with a pinch of salt.

---

The Infinity Gauntlet is made out of Uru, the same as Mjolnir, and Stark’s Gauntlet is made out of Vibranium, the same as Cap’s shield. We’ve seen these two metals come to blows with each other when Thor has hit Cap’s shield with Mjolnir over the years and it as much as dented it so who’s to say it is stronger? In fact Vibranium *is* the strongest metal on Earth.

> **Bruce Banner:** I don't follow. What comes out of Wakanda? *[looking at Steve's shield]*
>
> **Tony Stark:** The strongest metal on Earth.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

Add onto that, that the enchanted Uru is essentially just advanced science that people don’t understand and so call magic.

> **Thor:** Look your ancestors called it magic. You call it science. I come from a place where they're one and the same thing.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Lastly, note those who made the Stark Gauntlet: Tony, Banner and Rocket. Tony and Banner have had exposure studying Infinity Stones in the past and Rocket is an extremely skilled engineer. There’s also the possibility that they took the original Infinity Gauntlet from Thanos at the beginning of the film and so have improved upon the original design.

Comment: I like this but do we have a source for the Stark Gauntlet being made of Vibranium, I didn't get that in the movie?

Comment: @Paulie_D I just assumed it was, will have a look to double check.

Comment: I would like this to be true, but we have literally not a shred of evidence to suggest that Tony's gauntlet is made of Vibranium. For that matter Tony hasn't even been to Wakanda ever.

Comment: Also, energy dissipation is something that is not exclusively dependant from the material of any element. The material of the gauntlet could be lesser, but their ability (engineering) to bear the energy overcharge and, maybe, store it into batteries, could be far better than those of the original gauntlet.

Comment: We haven't seen tony visit Wakanda, but Okoye _is_ working with the Avengers throughout the movie, so I don't think availability of Vibranium is an issue. The bigger issue is, as mentioned, that there's no real evidence to suggest Tony used Vibranium. Perhaps he didn't use it because it would absorb the vibration of the snap :)

Answer (score 5):

This is, of course, mostly speculation.  But I think that it's reasonable speculation, regardless of whether or not it is accurate.

### Tony's Gauntlet survived because it wasn't as protective

Part of the Infinity Gauntlet's function was to protect the user from the full force of the Stones.

When

> The Hulk used Tony's Gauntlet,

It left him in significantly worse shape than than Thanos was at the end of Infinity War.  Obviously, it's possible that the difference was due to Thanos's inherent robustness, but it's also possible that the original Gauntlet was more protective than the new one.  And just like a strong resister generates more heat than a weak one, I'd expect that the more a Gauntlet protects its user, the more damage the Gauntlet itself would take.

It's also possible that

> Reversing Thanos's Snap

was less dangerous than the Snap itself.  Certainly Thanos took a great deal more damage when he

> destroyed the Stones

than when he Snapped, indicating that either different effects have different degrees of backlash, or that the damaged Gauntlet was less protective than the fully functioning one.